# Vee-Validate v3 server side validation in rule

Tags: vee-validate

Trying to do server side validation in a rule.  It is something like this:

```
        validate(value, {fname, fid } ) {    
            return(axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: 'xyz.php'             
            })
            .then(function (response) {
              return response.msg === 'available'
             }
            })
         )
        },
        message: 'Not available ', 
        params:[ 'fname', 'fid' ]
    });
```

However, I get no error message even though my request is returning with the proper validation.  I've found 2 examples, but both use the this.$refs (either .form or .observer) which I do not have access to in extend since it is outside of the Vue object. How do I go about setting errors in this situation?  Thanks in advance.

The template is this :

```
 <div class="w3-third">
                            <label>From</label>
                            <ValidationProvider vid="st" mode="eager" :rules="{'available': [res_date, endTime, 'starter', selectedField.id] }" v-slot="{ errors }">                        
                                <dropdown id="starttime" :options="startTimeOptions" v-model="startTime" ></dropdown> 
                                <span class="w3-red">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                            </ValidationProvider>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w3-third  ">
                            <label>Until</label>
                            <ValidationProvider vid="et"  mode="eager" :rules="{'available': [res_date, startTime, 'ender', selectedField.id] }" v-slot="{ errors }">                        
                                <dropdown id="endtime" :options="endTimeOptions"  v-model="endTime"></dropdown> 
                                <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
                            </ValidationProvider>

                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your validate function needs to return the promise that axios produces:

```
    validate(value, {fname, fid } ) {    
        return axios({
        //...
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Same result when returning the promise.  Looks like the return is correct , but no error message showing on validation provider.

Comment: I'm happy to take another look, but you'll have to flesh out the question - what does the relevant vue template look like?

Comment: I added the template to my original question.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue was because I was using my custom component, Dropdown, which didn't have v-model set in a way that worked with vee-validate.  So Ryley's answer about returning the promise was correct.